# How to read excel sheets in android program

Tags: android, database, excel

I have a database of 29 excel sheets which i need to use in my code. I converted those ecxel sheets in .xml format using ms excel so that i can use xmlparser to fetch data from it in my program. But the converted files i got have a very strange format and i am having trouble in reading that file and how will i write parser for it. Can any one suggest how can i use these excel sheets in my project.

give me any simple example for this small table so that i can use it for whole sheet

Aging_Bucket_Key    Aging_Bucket_Type   Aging_Bucket_Code   Aging_Bucket_Desc
1   Inventory   0 - 30 Days 0 - 30 Days
2   Inventory   31 - 60 Days    31 - 60 Days
3   Inventory   61 - 90 Days    61 - 90 Days
4   Inventory   More than 90 Days   More than 90 Days
5   Backlog 0 - 30 Days 0 - 30 Days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should download http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ library and try to implement it. this library provide read data of excel in android.

Comment: I tried that code. It is giving me desired output. I have silly doubt but plz tell me that how this java code can be used in android directly.

Answer (score 0):

[POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is good API for reading excel sheet.