# How to convert excel sheet into database of sqlite in android

Tags: android, excel, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an excel sheet on which I need to hit a few queries. I have successfully accessed the excel sheet in my project but now I have trouble hitting queries on it because I need to write code fetch even a small column. Is there any way that I can convert my excel sheet into the SQLite database? As it will simplify my work.
The Excel sheet is too big with 29 sheets in it. It is impossible to manually enter those values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357355/how-to-read-excel-sheets-in-android-program/7357391#7357391

Comment: I have already used this lib. But my problem is i don want to read excel sheet. I want to convert it into database, Its easy to hit queries for sqlite than writing code for each fetch to excel sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite is a relational database format, excel is a spreadsheet. There is no direct relationship between the two for there to be a generic conversion tool.

You do not mention if you need the formulae or formatting.  But you could use the code mentioned here, [How to read excel sheets in android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357355/how-to-read-excel-sheets-in-android-program/7357391#7357391).

Then it is up to you how you structure your sqlite database and save the values you've read.

Answer (score 11):

You have a few practical options:

1. You can open the Excel file directly in the app, as IanNorton said
2. You can convert the Excel to a SQLite file first, and then drop and read that SQLite file in the app.

   - This tool can convert the Excel file to SQLite for you - http://converttosqlite.com/

If you want to convert Excel to SQLite and query the SQLite DB in your app , use option #2. But if you  just want to read an Excel file straight in your app, use option #1.

Comment: Thanks, that really saved me a lot of time and energy

Comment: This is a better answer in my opinion.