# how to copy data from a local Excel sheet to sqlite database table in android

Tags: android, excel, sqlite

i have two excel sheet in my D drive i want to copy data from this to my Android Application to save it in sqlite database table and use it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that there is no direct relationship between excel and sqlite,
I can only think at 3 solutions:

1. you build your tables in sqlite (using SQLite Browser) and push it into your application
2. Use the Google SpreadSheets
3. You can use this answers: [How to convert excel sheet into database of sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412293/how-to-convert-excel-sheet-into-database-of-sqlite-in-android)