# Use Excel as a database from an Android app

Tags: android, database, excel

I want to create an Android app using Microsoft Excel as the database.

In the app, I would give input that would update an Excel file.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Google: `android excel database`

Answer (score 4):

In android a light weight  SQLite Database is provided along with the framework to fulfill your database requirements,Try using it.Its quite easy to use

1. [**Check the link for knowing about it in detail**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

   and also
2. **[How to convert excel sheet into database of sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412293/how-to-convert-excel-sheet-into-database-of-sqlite-in-android)**

There is no such ms excel integration in android as you are  asking.Try to alter your database requirements.For further explaination about your scenario,please comment.

Comment: Oh tanx , I'm pioneer in programming and developing an app , can u plz provide me info of 1.  how to link the sqllite db to my android app,        2. And how to transfer the data into the specified fields of the excel file

Comment: **Clarify first:**  There may be two scenarios, **1.** Installing the app and then creating the database and storing some data,or **2.**  you want to have an already created database while installation of the application

Comment: In the first scenario you mean that after insatalling the app into the mobile we have to create a db and store manually..?

Comment: It may be manually or it may be requesting some data by calling some URL and then storing the response in the created database

Comment: k , I will do with 2nd scenerio, creating the db while installing

Comment: It is not like that as you are thinking about second approach, [See this to know more about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device)

Comment: Sir nobalG Actually I want to store the data to the excel 1.I will create a page that will contain the fields of the input data to be entered 2.The given input data is to be updated into the excel file(that like u have said by SQLlite)3. next I will export that excel file to my PC AND then I shall take print out of that). Suggest me how to proceed .

Comment: Sir Nobal G did u get some idea of the app , can it be done

Comment: When you are taking input from the user ,save the data in the local database (on device) in sqlite,along with it, make a call to the API(sending the data) that will save your data on the servers .From the server(or your computer create an excel file of the data you are having and then get a print of it.)