# Regarding Dynamic Generation of Math and Science Formulas in Textview

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem with reading and displaying mathematics and science formula. They're not showing up like in the images given below. I'm displaying it in a `TextView`, and I used `setTypeface` to set the font as the "Gujarati" font.

Thank you in advance.

I want to display mathematics formula like:

[image]

... and also display science equations like:

[image]

And, how to read Excel sheet and store in SQLite database in Android? I don't use `.csv` because I store Gujarati data in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Excel ti SQLite3, a quick search lead me to these:

[How to convert excel sheet into database of sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412293/how-to-convert-excel-sheet-into-database-of-sqlite-in-android)

[How to read excel sheets in android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357355/how-to-read-excel-sheets-in-android-program)

http://www.razorsql.com/features/sqlite_import.html

Comment: hey i used razorsql for convert excel data in sqlite but it was not create table when i import data from excel sheet it was give me file is not db

Comment: how to store gujarati font in razorsql. i have excel file in that contain gujarati font of data now i want to store it in database how can do that right now it was give me ?????? ??? format

Answer (score 3):

You can display mathematical function using HTML code in string.xml file in value folder. Like example:

```
<string name="superscript"><html><i>a</i><sup>2</sup>+<i>y</i><sup>2</sup></html></string>
<string name="subscript"><html>f(x)<sub>1+x</sub></html></string>
```

and write in your xml file TextView:

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/superscript" />

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/subscript" />
```

for mathematical symbols and character, you can check this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

http://barzilai.org/math_sym.htm

http://www.myphysicslab.com/web_math.html

Comment: But we have lots of data so that contains my lines it will take long time so there is any other option or way. Thank you

Comment: how to store gujarati font in razorsql. i have excel file in that contain gujarati font of data now i want to store it in database how can do that right now it was give me ?????? ??? format – Jatin Patel

Answer (score 1):

For Solution of 1st problem  Use MAthJAX in android

http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498

its Quite easy

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageView and show the images of these expressions. This would be quite easy.