# Retrieve Excel Sheet data into Sqlite Database Android

Tags: android, excel, sqlite, android-sqlite

In Android application ,i should get large datas(nearly 500 coloums and 1000 rows) from Excel Sheet into Sqlite Database.
For that i have used the following code snippet,

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("Excel File Path in SDCard");
    HSSFWorkbook  wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Test");

    Iterator<?> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
    int index = 0;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()){

         HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
          if(index++ != 0){

             //In this stage i have storing each cell into database
              util.inserrDataToSqliteDb(dbManager, hssfRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue(),
   hssfRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue()  
    }
 }
```

When use this code it takes long time to get data from excel sheet. Taking all the rows without any iteration into database may be a good idea.
But i could not get any reference to do that one.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,

Comment: Any update to this question,me also having the same problem.Pls help me guys??

Comment: Is it possible to import excel sheet into sqlite db in android ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357355/how-to-read-excel-sheets-in-android-program/7357391#7357391